# How to Fix this CSS Vertical Step Progress

Tags: html, css

Here my current view of my HTML+CSS:

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/p3ea4zoq/

[image]

my current HTML:

```
<ul class="vertical-point-progress">
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
  <li>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</li>
  <li>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</li>
  <li>Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio.</li>
</ul>
```

my current CSS:

```
<style>
    .vertical-point-progress {
        max-width: 400px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        list-style-type: none;
        /* counter-reset: none; */
        margin: 0;
        font-family: Poppins;
    }
    .vertical-point-progress li {
        padding: 0 0 20px 50px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .vertical-point-progress li:after {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        content: "";
        /* counter-increment: none; */
        border: 1px solid #ADB9C7;
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 24px;
        width: 24px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 24px;
        background: #ADB9C7;
    }

    .vertical-point-progress li:before {
        position: absolute;
        left: 10.4px;
        top: 0;
        content: "";
        height: 100%;
        width: 0;
        border: 2px solid #EEF2F6;
    }

    /* .vertical-point-progress li:first-of-type:before {
    border: none;
    }

    .vertical-point-progress li:last-of-type:before {
    border: none;
    } */
</style>
```

What i want is (look at the grey line above the circle mark of first step progress, i need to add that line to my html+css). What should i do?

[image]

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: how much longer do you want?

Comment: i need it untill this problem is clear, i need that short line at the first Step and at the last Step, like the picture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a little line at the first Step and at the last Step, just add these styles at the bottom of the style tag.

```css
.vertical-point-progress li:first-child:before {
  top: -20px;    /* Adjust this value to modify the line height at the first Step */
  height: auto;
  bottom: 0px;
}
.vertical-point-progress li:last-child:before {
  height: auto;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 10px;  /* Adjust this value to modify the line height at the last Step */
}
```

**Edit**: Use `nth-child` to select nth of li element.

```css
.vertical-point-progress li:nth-child(2):after {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: sir can i ask again? how to give the color to specify circle of steps?

Comment: Check my new answer! Use `nth-child()` to access the nth item.